# How to align control buttons horizontally-bottom instead of vertically-right NgxImageViewer

Tags: css, angular, button, imageview

I am using NgxImageViewer and i want to display controls horizontally-bottom of the screen instead of vertically-right

Html

```
<ngx-image-viewer  [src]="images" [(index)]="imageIndex"></ngx-image-viewer>
```

Ts

```
config = {
    btnClass: 'default', // The CSS class(es) that will apply to the buttons
    zoomFactor: 0.1, // The amount that the scale will be increased by
    containerBackgroundColor: '#ccc', // The color to use for the background. This can provided in hex, or rgb(a).
    wheelZoom: true, // If true, the mouse wheel can be used to zoom in
    allowFullscreen: true, // If true, the fullscreen button will be shown, allowing the user to entr fullscreen mode
    allowKeyboardNavigation: false, // If true, the left / right arrow keys can be used for navigation
    btnIcons: { // The icon classes that will apply to the buttons. By default, font-awesome is used.
      zoomIn: 'fa fa-plus',
      zoomOut: 'fa fa-minus',
      rotateClockwise: 'fa fa-repeat',
      rotateCounterClockwise: 'fa fa-undo',
      next: 'fa fa-arrow-right',
      prev: 'fa fa-arrow-left',
      fullscreen: 'fa fa-arrows-alt',
    },
    btnShow: {
      zoomIn: true,
      zoomOut: true,
      rotateClockwise: true,
      rotateCounterClockwise: true,
      next: false,
      prev: false
    }
```

[Stackbliz url](https://angular-2wrbwp.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Make bottom of each button as same (say 15px). then add left: 50px, 75px, 100px etc respectively to each button. This should be done in CSS as there is no option in config from the code above.

Comment: can u provide me exact css for this please

Comment: Please show some courtesy and review the answers.

Comment: Participation of OP is low.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to add each button same `bottom` and different `right` or `left` something like:

```
.img-container button.default{
    bottom: 15px !important;
    display: inline;
}

button.default:nth-of-type(1){
    left: 0px;
}
button.default:nth-of-type(2){
    left: 45px;
}
button.default:nth-of-type(3){
    left: 90px;
}
button.default:nth-of-type(4){
    left: 135px;
}
```

**Note**: consider to put styles in your `styles.css` file.
working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuunne)

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal do you add it to styles.css of src folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS. Hope this works. Basically you are moving all buttons to bottom and then placing them from left-right.

```
.img-container button.default{
    bottom: 15px;
}
.img-container > button.default:nth-of-type(2):not(#ngx-fs-btn){
    left: 45px;
}
.img-container > button.default:nth-of-type(3):not(#ngx-fs-btn){
    left: 90px;
}
.img-container > button.default:nth-of-type(4):not(#ngx-fs-btn){
    left: 135px;
}
```

Comment: classes like ```_ngcontent-c1``` are generated by angular and we shouldn't use them in our css.

Comment: it works but it's not correct and will make problem if something related changes in dom. correct it and i will back my downvote.

Comment: can you explain what is ```not(#ngx-fs-btn)``` ?

Comment: There is a button on top right corner of page. This selector will prevent that from being in target.